# Fraction-decimal(and vice versa) converter

Tags: java, decimal, fractions

I have 2 parts of code, the first one being converting fraction to decimal, and the second one being converting decimal to fraction.

However, I have to combine the two piece of code together and I have no idea.I want it to detect the input as either doubles or fraction and convert it to the other.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ExcerciseEleven  {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Numerator: ");
        int numerator = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Denominator: ");
        int denominator = sc.nextInt();
        if (denominator == 0) {
            System.out.println("Can't divide by zero");
        }
        else {
            double fraction = (double)numerator / denominator;
            System.out.println(fraction);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Fractions {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double decimal;
        double originalDecimal;
        int LIMIT = 12;
        int denominators[] = new int[LIMIT + 1];
        int numerator, denominator, temp;
        int MAX_GOODNESS = 100;

        // Get a number to be converted to a fraction
        if (args.length == 1) {
            decimal = Double.valueOf(args[0]).doubleValue();
        } else {
            // No number was given, so just use pi
            assert args.length == 0; 
            decimal = Math.PI;
        }
        originalDecimal = decimal;

        // Display the header information
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Program by David Matuszek");
        System.out.println("Input decimal number to be converted: " + decimal);
        System.out.println();

        // Compute all the denominators
        System.out.println("All computed denominators:");
        int i = 0;
        while (i < LIMIT + 1) {
            denominators[i] = (int)decimal;
            System.out.print(denominators[i] + "  ");
            decimal = 1.0 / (decimal - denominators[i]);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        // Compute the i-th approximation
        int last = 0;
        while (last < LIMIT) {

            // Print out the denominators used in this computation
            System.out.print("Using these " + (last + 1) + " denominators: ");
            for (int j = 0; j <= last; j++) {
                System.out.print(denominators[j] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            // Initialize variables used in computation
            numerator = 1;
            denominator = 1;
            temp = 0;

            // Do the computation
            int current = last;
            while (current >= 0) {
                denominator = numerator;
                numerator = (numerator * denominators[current]) + temp;
                temp = denominator;
                current = current - 1;
            }
            last = last + 1;

            // Display results
            double value = (double)numerator/denominator;
            int goodness = denominators[last];
            double error = 100 * Math.abs(value - originalDecimal) / originalDecimal;

            System.out.print("fraction = " + (int)numerator + "/" +
                             (int)denominator);
            System.out.print(", value = " + value);
            System.out.print(", goodness = " + goodness);
            System.out.println(", error = " + (int)error + "%");
            System.out.println();

            // Exit early if we have reached our goodness criterion
            if (Math.abs(goodness) > MAX_GOODNESS) break;
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your combined program supposed to do?

Comment: I was thinking it could detect the input as either doubles or fraction and convert it to the other.

Comment: You could use à RegEx I guess or Check if the input contains a ´.´ or a ´/´ with contains()

Comment: If that's what you were thinking, were you also thinking that we would read your mind to know that?

Comment: @YassinHajaj Regex is overkill, and checking for a character is better done using `indexOf`.

Comment: Youre right Andreas. As always :).

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing it all on one prompt, I would make two static methods Fraction.TryParse(), and I would use the built in Double.TryParse(), if decimal.TryParse returns true then you do in fact have a decimal. If it returns false, then you have a Fraction, therefore you have to use the same string you passed into Decimal.TryParse() in Fraction.TryParse(). Of course you will need some sanity checks in your Fraction.TryParse() method. The prompt could look something like this:

```
Enter Decimal/Fraction: 3.14
Enter Decimal/Fraction: 1 + 1/2
Enter Decimal/Fraction: 1 1/2
Enter Decimal/Fraction: 1 (1/2)
```

You see, if you want this all on one line you need some way to be able to delimit the characters, like a space, or brackets, or simply a + sign which would be mathematically accurate. If it is all on one line it also simplifies your program a little bit because you don't have multiple prompts for one object. The "1 (1/2)" input is not technically mathematically accurate, but you can kind of see how the data is supposed to be structured, you just can't be mathematically rigid with that prompt.

Here I am using the fraction one and one half, your implementation doesn't have a mixed number implementation, but you could just input 1/2 or something, just regular fractions.